# How accurate, on average, AML services are? Is there a better way to do what they do?

Tags: blockchain, wallets, addresses, kyc

I'm working on a exchange where crypto and fiat will be exchanged. Fiat in the physical form, namely, a customer will physically come to a place.

I've been suggested to integrate an AML service **for crypto**. That is, I'd use REST API of an external **AML service** to verify that a customer's wallet is more or less clean, before making a deal with him.

However, after having done research, I haven't found any comprehensive feedback of those who have used AML services for crypto, at all.

Theoretically, even if they may be useful, but how would one know how accurate a service is? How would one know that a service even works, has some data to pull from, rather one pretend to work?

Is there information about AML services for crypto? **Or is there a better, different, way to achive the same thing?**

Answer (score 1):

Using or providing a AML solution is required when running a onramp in some jurisdictions. Most likely it will grow into more jurisdictions.

The ones I have seen report on addresses and these checks/reports can of course be verified with other parties. Goobit group has created something they call the AML-Desk that I know has been used by the game Habbo created by Azerion.

There are oracles available that provide some sanction lists etc.
[Chainalysis oracles](https://go.chainalysis.com/chainalysis-oracle-docs.html)

However, there is also inherent value (or perceived value) in adding a 3rd party AML provider. It can reduce bias or reduce chances of internal manipulation. It is common in the tradfi world and one can assume that regulatory bodies will keep pushing for this.